# Oracle - View source of builtin package

Tags: sql, oracle, package, oracle19c

How can I view the source of a builtin package in Oracle 19c?

I'm interested in the `SYS.UTL_SMTP` package.

I don't have access to the file system, only login to the database.

Comment: What do you like to know?

Comment: Most if not all of the built-in pkgs are wrapped, specifically to prevent the code from being seen.  Oracle is protecting their proprietary code.  Your not having access to the file system says you are not a privileged user, so even less need to see Oracle's proprietary code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling it?

If you google search **plsql unwrap** the first link is an online tool that allows you to paste in wrapped code and will show you the unwrapped code.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the code to unwrap it?

Comment: if you are looking for the wrapped code, you can get it using any IDE (SQL Developer, Toad, PL/SQL Developer). It is IDE specific how you get the package body wrapped code though. Also, looking at internal Oracle package will likely not reveal much of the internal workings as it is likely calling code written in C or other compiled code.

Comment: Do you know how I would do it using SQL Developer?